# Curl and SSL Issue

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, libcurl

We have our app using libCurl(version 7.39) and OpenSSL(version 1.0.1e) for secure connections(web services).

On most of the machines everything works as expected but there are few machines on which the following is the error thrown up by the libCURL.

"Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates. Please try again after some time."

on further debugging curl, we could find that the error code thrown up was 10054.

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that your OpenSSL can't find system CA certificates?

Comment: The certificate file exist in location where the application expects and path is set properly to curl. In most of the machines it is working only in few we are facing the problem.

Comment: 1 - curl doesn't have any such error string internally. 2 what does "error 10054" mean? curl has no such error code.

Comment: Sorry about 10054, we are getting error code CURLE_SSL_CACERT when passed to function curl_easy_strerror() got the above message. "Please try again after some time" - this message is appended by our application.

Comment: Find out what the difference between these machines is. Maybe they are located behind some firewall which does SSL interception?

Comment: Thanks for your advise, i will see if there are any differences between the firewall settings.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if on those "few machines", you have a different set of CA certificates that don't include the necessary ones needed to verify the server you connect to.

Make sure you have the same CA cert bundle on all machines.

Worst case, this is an actual active MITM attack you see...

Comment: The CA certificate is shipped along with the application, so there is no chance of having different certificates on different machines and Thanks for the reply.